# Power Automate compare column items of different sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am completely a Power Automate and SharePoint noob. I am sorry if the answer to my question is simple.
I have explained what I want to achieve using Power Automate Flow in the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umwVE.png)

Comment: Can you type out what you've put in the image into your question itself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, it can be achieved by using OOTB lookup column.

1.Go to List Settings > Columns > Create column:
[image]
2.Select column type "Lookup (information already on this site)" and check as shown below:
[image]
[image]

Demonstration:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried using this feature too...but here we need to enter the value ourselves... I want to automate it with power automate.